# DateTime.TryParse with different culture

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, cultureinfo, invariantculture

I have two dates as per below and have my local culture is "en-IN"

```
string enInDateValue = "13-12-2021 12:00:00"; // dd/mm/yyyy
string enUSDateValue = "12-13-2021 12:00:00"; // mm/dd/yyyy
```

If I run the below code with Invariant Culture it date gets parsed with enUSDate.

```
DateTime.TryParse(enInDateValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out result)
DateTime.TryParse(enUSDateValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out result)
```

To solve the problem below is the code I am using and it is parsing the dates per culture.

```
public static bool DateTimeTryParse(string date, out DateTime result)
    {
        return (
            DateTime.TryParse(date, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out result) ||
              DateTime.TryParse(date, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out result) ||
              DateTime.TryParse(date, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out result)
        );
    }
```

If it fails with only Invariant Culture it goes to Current and same for UI Culture

**So wanted to ask if that is the right to do? Or is there any other way around?**

Comment: No, you need to know the format beforehand. For example, how do you know if `01-02-2021` is 1st February or 2nd January?

Comment: So is 01/02/2021 the first of the second, or the second of the first? You have a bigger problem here

Comment: @DavidG beat me to it , with the exact same date!

Comment: @TheGeneral Haha!

Comment: The computer isn't magic - it can't guess the meaning alas. If you have dates, they need to be in a set and well defined format.

Comment: Or you need to store the format (culture) along with the date

Comment: @DavidG yes that is the question, if api sending me us format and my local format is enIN and storing data to offline db how can I convert the date with Invariant culture?
I hope you have negated the question but I was not clear and have doubt hence asked is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the expected format explicitly. This small sample may be helpful:

```
        string date1 = "12-13-2021";
        string date2 = "13-12-2021";

        string format1 = "MM-dd-yyyy";
        string format2 = "dd-MM-yyyy";

        DateTime parsedDate1, parsedDate2;

        bool success1 = DateTime.TryParseExact(date1, format1, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate1);
        bool success2 = DateTime.TryParseExact(date2, format2, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate2);

        if (success1)
            Console.WriteLine($"First date parsed successfully: {parsedDate1.ToString("yyyy,MMM,dd,ddd")}");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("First date failed to parse");

        if (success2)
            Console.WriteLine($"Second date parsed successfully: {parsedDate2.ToString("yyyy,MMM,dd,ddd")}");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Second date failed to parse");
```

Comment: If you don't have enough rep to comment, then go get some rep. You only need a few points so should only take a few minutes.